# Copy Active workbook to another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The following vba is giving me an error and I can't figure it out. What I would like to do is take all the worksheets in my active workbook and copy them to another workbook that I open using GetOpenFilename.

When I run it, I get the error Type Mismatch.

Any suggestions from you experts as to what I am doing wrong here? I would really appreciate your help with this.

Smiddy

```
Dim FromBook As Variant
Dim ToBook As Workbook
Dim FromSheet As Worksheet
Dim ToSheet As Worksheet
Dim strFileName As String


Set FromBook = ActiveSheet

strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select File")


If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set ToSheet = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)


Dim ws As Worksheet, flg As Boolean


For Each FromSheet In FromBook.Sheets
        FromSheet.Copy After:=ToSheet
Next FromSheet
```

Tried to copy active sheet to sheet I opened. Expected to copy all worksheets from Active workbook into the workbook I opened. Received a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: Workbooks.Open returns a Workbook object, not a Worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes as below

```
Dim FromBook As Workbook
Dim ToBook as Workbook
....

Set FromBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ToBook = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

..

For Each FromSheet In FromBook.Sheets
        FromSheet.Copy After:=ToBook.Sheets(1)
Next
```

Everything else seems perfect

Comment: In that case, the code will fail at the copy-statement - unless you assign something to `ToSheet` or change the statement

Comment: ToSheet is renamed to ToBook as Workbooks.Open() will result workbook renamed var accordingly